# how can i check if a compressed file(of all formats- zip/rar/tar/uue) is password protected, without extracting it in c#?

Tags: c#, file, zip, dotnetzip, chilkat

I am developing a small utility in c#, where I am inserting many compressed files. These files are in different extensions(such as .zip, .rar, .tar, .uue) Now I do not want to extract these files, but I just want to check if these files are password protected or not.

I have used DotNetZip.dll for the files with .zip extension, which is working fine. I found Chilkat dll for .rar files.

Can anyone provide me other dlls for other extensions or a better solution for all compressed files? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can also use SharpZipLib , it is written in C# for .NET platform and works with most compression formats. https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/

Answer (score 1):

Using SharpZipLib, the following code works. And by works I mean entry.IsCrypted returns true or false based on whether or not there is a password for the first entry in the zip file.

```
var file = @"c:\testfile.zip";
FileStream fileStreamIn = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
ZipInputStream zipInStream = new ZipInputStream(fileStreamIn);
ZipEntry entry = zipInStream.GetNextEntry();
Console.WriteLine("IsCrypted: " + entry.IsCrypted);
```

There's a simple tutorial on using SharpZipLib on CodeProject.

Thus a simple implementation looks something like:

```
public static bool IsPasswordProtectedZipFile(string path)
{
    using (FileStream fileStreamIn = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (ZipInputStream zipInStream = new ZipInputStream(fileStreamIn))
    {
        ZipEntry entry = zipInStream.GetNextEntry();
        return entry.IsCrypted;
    }
}
```

Note there's no real error handling or anything...

ref:[How to validate that a file is a password protected ZIP file, using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640223/how-to-validate-that-a-file-is-a-password-protected-zip-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: this works with .zip extension. I want solution for .rar, .tar, .uue extensions as well.

Comment: just change all types or formats to zip and after checking again change into old extensions   good luck

Comment: these files are extreme crucial and I cant play with their extensions. :)

Comment: your file will not lost any data it will just change your file extension header nothing else so dont be afraid and try this trick good luck brother